# How to get two values of $x$ from $y=x-x^2$ given constant $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given some $y$, there will be two solutions for $x$ for equation of $y = x-x^2$. I am unable to obtain the equation for those. Can anyone show how I would get this?

Comment: Google "quadratic formula."

Comment: Hmm. $y=x-x^2$ IS an equation?

Answer (score 5):

$$x^2-x+y=0$$
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It can be computed like this:
\begin{align*}y&=x-x^2\\x^2-x&=-y\\x^2-2\cdot\tfrac12x+\tfrac14&=\tfrac14-y\\(x-\tfrac12)^2&=\tfrac14-y\\\pm(x-\tfrac12)&=\sqrt{\tfrac14-y}\\x&=\tfrac12\pm\sqrt{\tfrac14-y}\end{align*}
In real numbers you obviously need $y\ge\tfrac14$ for this to have a solution.